# How do you do NAT traversal for RTP media using Kamailio for signalling?

Tags: sip, linphone, kamailio, nat-traversal, ice-protocol

There are three devices in question.

1. A VoIP phone behind NAT
2. My own Kamailio Server on an EC2 instance.
3. The Linphone application for android on my phone.

My phone is on mobile data, and since I have an MVNO, it appears to be NATed as well (private IP like 192.0.0.X).

My problem, is that Although SIP signalling is working just fine, I can't get either device to receive the other's RTP media streams.

I've defined WITH_NAT in the kamailio.cfg, but it doesn't seem to be helping with gathering candidates.  Here's the invite before and after passing through Kamailio.

Before:

```
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.0.0.4:46244;branch=z9hG4bK.bLB4chm4B;rport.
From: "the app" <sip:105@<SERVERDOMAIN>>;tag=EHCGj~8d5.
To: sip:104@<SERVERDOMAIN>.
CSeq: 20 INVITE.
Call-ID: SyOH-iCt1A.
Max-Forwards: 70.
Supported: replaces, outbound, gruu.
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, NOTIFY, MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE, INFO, UPDATE.
Content-Type: application/sdp.
Content-Length: 721.
Contact: <sip:105@172.56.20.144:43565;transport=udp>;expires=3600;received="sip:172.56.20.144:43565";+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:f102067f-da3a-00f6-9530-ee66544ec6b4>".
User-Agent: <USERAGENT>/0.2.1-debug (Mobile Dev Environment 1) LinphoneSDK/4.1-366-g1b22291 (master) (belle-sip/1.6.3).
.
v=0.
o=105 911 2837 IN IP4 192.0.0.4.
s=Talk.
c=IN IP4 192.0.0.4.
t=0 0.
a=ice-pwd:42da1553a4faaaf4b57c93f2.
a=ice-ufrag:894dda61.
a=rtcp-xr:rcvr-rtt=all:10000 stat-summary=loss,dup,jitt,TTL voip-metrics.
m=audio 7078 RTP/AVP 0 8 101.
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000.
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2130706303 192.0.0.4 7078 typ host.
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 2130706302 192.0.0.4 7079 typ host.
a=rtcp-fb:* trr-int 1000.
a=rtcp-fb:* ccm tmmbr.
m=video 9078 RTP/AVP 96.
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000.
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=42801F.
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2130706303 192.0.0.4 9078 typ host.
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 2130706302 192.0.0.4 9079 typ host.
a=rtcp-fb:* trr-int 1000.
a=rtcp-fb:* ccm tmmbr.
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli.
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir.
```

After:

```
Record-Route: <sip:<SERVERDOMAIN>:<PORT>;lr;nat=yes>.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP <SERVERDOMAIN>:<PORT>;branch=z9hG4bKdd88.20b5965a3ea168d68a6b0603ebaa6c80.0.
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.0.0.4:46244;received=172.56.20.144;branch=z9hG4bK.bLB4chm4B;rport=43565.
From: "the app" <sip:105@<SERVERDOMAIN>>;tag=EHCGj~8d5.
To: sip:104@<SERVERDOMAIN>.
CSeq: 20 INVITE.
Call-ID: SyOH-iCt1A.
Max-Forwards: 69.
Supported: replaces, outbound, gruu.
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, NOTIFY, MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE, INFO, UPDATE.
Content-Type: application/sdp.
Content-Length: 721.
Contact: <sip:105@172.56.20.144:43565;transport=udp;alias=172.56.20.144~43565~1>;expires=3600;received="sip:172.56.20.144:43565";+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:f102067f-da3a-00f6-9530-ee66544ec6b4>".
User-Agent: <USERAGENT>/0.2.1-debug (Mobile Dev Environment 1) LinphoneSDK/4.1-366-g1b22291 (master) (belle-sip/1.6.3).
.
v=0.
o=105 911 2837 IN IP4 192.0.0.4.
s=Talk.
c=IN IP4 192.0.0.4.
t=0 0.
a=ice-pwd:42da1553a4faaaf4b57c93f2.
a=ice-ufrag:894dda61.
a=rtcp-xr:rcvr-rtt=all:10000 stat-summary=loss,dup,jitt,TTL voip-metrics.
m=audio 7078 RTP/AVP 0 8 101.
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000.
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2130706303 192.0.0.4 7078 typ host.
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 2130706302 192.0.0.4 7079 typ host.
a=rtcp-fb:* trr-int 1000.
a=rtcp-fb:* ccm tmmbr.
m=video 9078 RTP/AVP 96.
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000.
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=42801F.
a=candidate:1 1 UDP 2130706303 192.0.0.4 9078 typ host.
a=candidate:1 2 UDP 2130706302 192.0.0.4 9079 typ host.
a=rtcp-fb:* trr-int 1000.
a=rtcp-fb:* ccm tmmbr.
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli.
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir.
```

It's the same story for inbound calls.

I was expecting the nathelper module to add something like

```
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 1694498815 <SOME_PUBLIC_IP> <SOME_PUBLIC_PORT> typ srflx raddr
192.0.0.4 rport 7078
```

but clearly it is not.  I can modify `o=` and `c=` in the headers to use the IP that the server received the invite from, but **how is the server suppose to know which ports the RTP media should be sent to?**  The only ports the server *could* know are

1. The port that the invite was sent from (private and public side)
2. The ports provided in the sdp.  But these are on the private-side.  Surely they would be different on the public-side?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: hey, did you try rtpengine? it helps you to fix natted problems. https://kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.2.x/modules/rtpengine.html#rtpengine.p.write_sdp_pv you can change c and o line with rtpengine ip-address. rtp flows over rtpengine.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup rtpproxy or rtpengine.

Here is the simplest procedure for installing and configuring rtpproxy with Kamailio:

1- install rtpproxy

```
apt install rtpproxy
```

2- Enter these 2 lines in rtpproxy configuration file (/etc/default/rtpproxy):

```
CONTROL_SOCK=udp:127.0.0.1:7722
EXTRA_OPTS="-l IP-address"
```

IP-address is the external IP address of your host.

3- Enter this define near the top of Kamailio configuration file (/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg):

```
#!define WITH_NAT
```

4- Restart rtpproxy

```
systemctl restart rtpproxy
```

5- Restart Kamailio

```
systemctl restart kamailio
```

INVITE and 200 OK relayed by Kamailio should then have their SDP Contact IPs and Ports replaced with the ones for rtpproxy

Note: I noticed at least one of the UAC should use TCP Transport for the above to work.